# Can i get the members of a Mail-Enabled security group inside my automated workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, office-365, flow, power-automate

We have the following Mail-Enabled Security group:

[image]

So my question is, can I get the members of a Mail-Enabled security group inside my automated workflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **List group members** action available in **Office 365 Groups** connector in Power automate flows to fetch the members of Mail enabled security groups like:

[image]

You have to enter the group ID of Mail enabled security group in above action which you can get from admin center:

[image]

**Documentation**: [List group members](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365groups/#list-group-members)

Comment: but will this support mail-enabled groups or it is only designed  for offcie 365 groups?

Comment: I have tried it with mail enabled security group & it works fine for me. Check the second screenshot I attached >> you can see it is a mail enabled security group only.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the Send an HTTP request action in the Office 365 Groups connector to do it. This action enables you to make calls to the Microsoft Graph. The operation you want is [List Members](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

To use this operation you'll need the Id of the group, which is a GUID. You can get this by selecting the group in the Microsoft 365 admin center and extracting the Id from the URL. For example:

```
https://admin.microsoft.com/#/groups/:/GroupDetails/c9f5aa52-b267-4ca9-8d89-caf67a698886/3
```

[image]

Comment: ok will try this for sure... thanks a lot